# Problem with sending mulltiple messages from server to client usign Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets, java-threads

I am trying to do simple banking application but i encountered problem, my server only sends 1 message instead of sending all of them. My App consists of 3 Files

```
package com.kiszka.server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class BankServer extends Thread {
    private final Socket socket;
    private static volatile Map<String,String> accAccessData = new HashMap<>();
    private static volatile boolean admitAccess = false;
    public BankServer(Socket socket) {
        accInfo();
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
//            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
//            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            for(;;){
                checkAccAccess(socket);
            }
        } finally {
            try{
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    public void accInfo(){
        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("accInfo.csv"))){
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                String[] parts = line.split(",");
                if(parts.length>=2){
                    String key = parts[0].trim();
                    String val = parts[1].trim();
                    accAccessData.put(key,val);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : accAccessData.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + ", Value: " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    public static void checkAccAccess(Socket socket){
        String value;
        int counter = 0;
        try {
            BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            for(;;){
                output.println("Please insert your account Number");
                String input = inputReader.readLine();
                if(!accAccessData.containsKey(input)){
                    output.println("Invalid Account Number");
                } else{
                    value = accAccessData.get(input);
                    break;
                }
            }
            while(counter<3){
                output.println("Please insert PIN to your account");
                String input = inputReader.readLine();
                if(!input.equals(value)){
                    counter++;
                }
                if(input.equals(value)){
                    output.println("Access granted");
                    admitAccess = true;
                    break;
                }
                if(counter == 3){
                    output.println("Access denied");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.kiszka.server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class ServerRun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000)){
            for(;;){
                new BankServer(serverSocket.accept()).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.kiszka.client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClientRun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",5000)){
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input;
            for(;;){
                String response = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println(response);
                input = scanner.nextLine();
                writer.println(input);
            }
        } catch(IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is when I type in wrong input it will only prints something like this
Please insert your account Number
25
Invalid Account Number

and nothing more.

But it should like

Please insert your account Number
25
Invalid Account Number
Please insert your account Number

Sometimes it throws java.net.SocketException, i dont have an idea how to solve this problem to make this program sends all messages then waits for input from client